# Django : reverse is not resolving url for inbuilt password reset

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to use inbuilt password reset from Django.
My urls.py is as follows.

```
app_name = 'recruiter'

urlpatterns= [
#urls
]

urlpatterns += [
url(r'^password_reset_done/$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^password_reset/$', password_reset, name='password_reset'),
url(r'^password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$', password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^password_reset_complete/$', password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

If I go like this then it gives error on this line of inbuilt function.

```
reverse('password_reset')
```

If I remove `app_name = 'recruiter'` then It works fine but namespacing is removed for other app functions. How can I resolve this ?

Also if I remove `app_name = 'recruiter'` and try to reset password then after submitting email I get error on this line.

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

error is like:

```
NoReverseMatch at /recruiter/password_reset/

Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb64': 'Mw', u'token': u'4fd-f1aeba7ed3a5410a30da'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['recruiter/password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the namespace in the call to reverse.

```
reverse('app_name:password_reset')
```

Or move your password reset URLs to a separate urls.py without a namespace.

Comment: reverse() call is in inbuilt function so I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `post_reset_redirect` and `email_template_name` as arguments in your URL:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', password_reset, {'email_template_name': 'recruiter/password_reset_email.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'recruiter:password_reset_done'}, name='password_reset'),
```

Now it will redirect to `recruiter:password_reset_done` and you can use your own email template in `recruiter/templates/recruiter/password_reset_email.html` with the proper namespacing for `password_reset_confirm`:

```
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'recruiter:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Note that you can also pass `template_name` to the URL to use your own password reset template:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'recruiter/password_reset.html', 'email_template_name': 'recruiter/password_reset_email.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'recruiter:password_reset_done'}, name='password_reset'),
```